# UIImageView fill image with color and border

Tags: swift, imageview

I have UIImageView with different types of shape(circle or rect or oval or hexagon) image. While user selects I need to change background and add border with red color.
Tried with layer.borderColor and layer.borderWidth, but it always draws rectangle around image view. Also tried function:

```
    func drawOutline(imageKeof: CGFloat = 0.2, color: UIColor = .white) -> UIImage? {
     let outlinedImageRect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: size.width * imageKeof, height: size.height * imageKeof)
     let imageRect = CGRect(x: size.width * (imageKeof - 1) * 0.5, y: size.height * (imageKeof - 1) * 0.5, width: size.width, height: size.height)
     UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(outlinedImageRect.size, false, imageKeof)
     draw(in: outlinedImageRect)
     let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
     context!.setBlendMode(.sourceIn)
     context!.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
     context!.fill(outlinedImageRect)
     draw(in: imageRect)
     let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
     UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage
}
```

It draws the border around original image, but I need just white background instead of image.

[image: I need white oval with red border]

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve]? if you don't want any color around your image just pass `.clear`